# add multiple objects to object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to combine and add few objects into a new object.

```
let data = {}

let status = true

let res = [{
    "quantity": 82,
    "startDate": "2021-05-04T02:09:00Z",
    "unit": "bpm"
  },
  {
    "quantity": 79,
    "startDate": "2021-05-09T02:09:00Z",
    "unit": "bpm"
  }
]
```

Expected output

```
data = {

    "status" : true,

    "res" : [{
    "quantity": 82,
    "startDate": "2021-05-04T02:09:00Z",
    "unit": "bpm"
  },
  {
    "quantity": 79,
    "startDate": "2021-05-09T02:09:00Z",
    "unit": "bpm"
  }
]


}
```

I need to add "status" and "res" into "data" object.
How can i do this??
Any suggestion would be great!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's what you need

```js
let data = {}

let status = true

let res = [{
    "quantity": 82,
    "startDate": "2021-05-04T02:09:00Z",
    "unit": "bpm"
  },
  {
    "quantity": 79,
    "startDate": "2021-05-09T02:09:00Z",
    "unit": "bpm"
  }
]
 
data = {status,...res}

console.debug(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

The following command may be readable, understandable.

```js
let data = {}

let status = true

let res = [{
    "quantity": 82,
    "startDate": "2021-05-04T02:09:00Z",
    "unit": "bpm"
  },
  {
    "quantity": 79,
    "startDate": "2021-05-09T02:09:00Z",
    "unit": "bpm"
  }
]

data = {res, status} // short command of data = { res: res, status: status}
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just assign to the properties you want:

```
data.status = status;
data.res = res;
```